# running `ln -s` doesn't work in npm postinstall

Tags: npm, symlink, package.json, post-install

I'm wanting to create a symlink in my package.json:

"postinstall":"ln -s ../../dist foo/dist"

however nothing appears.

Command works fine in terminal.

Maybe I should use a terminal emulator to cater for windows?

Answer (score 0):

System: `Ubuntu 16`
Npm: `3.5.2`

In file `package.json` I have

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ln -fs a b"
  }
}
```

In catalog I have the following files

```
ls -la
drwxrwxr-x   6 daniel daniel 4096 maj 15 09:51 .
drwxrwxr-x   4 daniel daniel 4096 maj 14 21:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 daniel daniel    0 maj 15 09:50 a
-rw-rw-r--   1 daniel daniel   55 maj 15 09:50 package.json
```

I use command

```
npm install
```

That prints

```
 undefined postinstall /home/daniel
 ln -fs a b

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1
npm WARN frontend No repository field.
npm WARN frontend No license
```

Then I list files again:

```
ls -la
drwxrwxr-x   6 daniel daniel 4096 maj 15 09:51 .
drwxrwxr-x   4 daniel daniel 4096 maj 14 21:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 daniel daniel    0 maj 15 09:50 a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 daniel daniel    1 maj 15 09:51 b -> a
-rw-rw-r--   1 daniel daniel   55 maj 15 09:50 package.json
```

Try reproduce these commands and let me know if it helps.